# In a Snowflake stored procedure, how do you use a query output to change a variable outside the execution statement?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USAGE_MONITOR;
USE DATABASE USAGE_MONITOR;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALC_METERING_HISTORY_TREND() 
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
as
$$
var mult = 2;
$$;
```

I am trying to change the value of mult based on the latest value of the SERVICE_LEVEL column in Snowflake.Organization_usage.usage_in_currency_daily.

Now I know that I can use the value of mult inside a snowflake.execute() statement, but I'm not sure how to extract a value from inside an execution to change a variable outside it.

I used the following code to get the data I need

```
SELECT SERVICE_LEVEL
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.USAGE_IN_CURRENCY_DAILY
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But referencing the mult variable from inside the snowflake.execute fails.

I tried something like this

```
var serviceLevel = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
       `SELECT SERVICE_LEVEL 
        FROM SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.USAGE_IN_CURRENCY_DAILY 
        ORDER BY DATE 
        DESC LIMIT 1;`
        } );
if (serviceLevel !== 'Standard') {
    mult = 3.7;
} else {
    mult= 2;
}
```

to get it to set the variable, but even that didn't work. and fails with error

> Error:ocedure CALC_METERING_HISTORY_TREND: (line 1)"

That's not a copy error; it actually said 'ocedure'

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USAGE_MONITOR;
USE DATABASE USAGE_MONITOR;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALC_METERING_HISTORY_TREND() 
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
as
$$
var mult = 2;
var result = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
   `SELECT SERVICE_LEVEL 
    FROM SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.USAGE_IN_CURRENCY_DAILY 
    ORDER BY DATE DESC 
    LIMIT 1;`
  } );
var row = result.fetchOne();
if (row && row[0] > 1) {
    mult = 3.7;
}
return mult.toString();
$$;
```

Comment: Error:ocedure CALC_METERING_HISTORY_TREND: (line 3) - Same error as mine.

Comment: I think the Javascript var, 'result' in this case, isn't actually supposed to take the value of the output of the Snowflake execute statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALC_METERING_HISTORY_TREND() 
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
as
$$
var mult = 0;
var result_set1 = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
       `SELECT SERVICE_LEVEL 
        FROM SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.USAGE_IN_CURRENCY_DAILY 
        ORDER BY USAGE_DATE 
        DESC LIMIT 1;`
        } );

if(result_set1.next()){
    var serviceLevel = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
    
    if (serviceLevel !== 'Standard') {
        mult = 3.7;
    } else {
        mult= 2;
    }
}
return mult.toString();
$$;
```

BTW In your SQL you had:

```
ORDER BY DATE
```

I assume you meant:

```
ORDER BY USAGE_DATE
```